# Какую библиотеку использовать для видеозаписи с IP-камер C#

Tags: c#, видео, поиск-библиотек, vlc

Сейчас начал модернизировать свою программу по видеонаблюдению с IP-камер на языке c#.

До этого я использовал LibVLCSharp: каждая камера писалась в своём потоке, я инициализировал либу, передавал в неё свои аргументы (rtsp ссылка камеры, путь куда будет писаться видосик), но проблема в том, что часть видосиков была с битым кодеком (это где-то треть от всех видосиков за день).

Первый вопрос - можно ли это как-то пофиксить, может, кто сталкивался с таким? Само видео имеет нормальный размер, но когда я его пытаюсь открыть в vlc - пишет ошибку о некорректности видеокодеков, т.е. я могу просмотреть только стопкадр без видео- и аудиодорожек.
Ранее я уже задавал вопрос на их форуме, но не получил никакого ответа, который бы мне помог.

Я решил использовать библиотеку ffmpeg, но столкнулся с проблемой, что каждая запись вызывает новый процесс ffmeg.exe, который выжирает по 20-40мб оперативы и ~2% ЦП, вызываю я эту либу по аналогии с vlc -> указываю путь exe-шника и передаю аргументы.

Кусок кода, как я вызываю ffmpeg:

```
public static Task<bool> ExecuteFfmpegAsync(string input, string output,
            Dictionary<string, string> beforeInput = null,
            Dictionary<string, string> beforeOutput = null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(output))
                throw new ArgumentException("input or output cannot be null or empty");

            var inputParameters = beforeInput == null || !beforeInput.Any()
                ? "$$"
                : $"{string.Join(" ", beforeInput.Select(kv => $"{kv.Key} {kv.Value}"))}";
            var outputParameters = beforeOutput == null || !beforeOutput.Any()
                ? "$$"
                : $"{string.Join(" ", beforeOutput.Select(kv => $"{kv.Key} {kv.Value}"))}";

            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
            {
                string typeOS = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? "win-x64" : "win-x86";
                string path = Path.Combine("runtimes/" + typeOS + "/lib/" + "ffmpeg.exe");
                string args = inputParameters + " -i " + input + " " + outputParameters + " " + output;
                string arg = $"{Path.Combine("runtimes", Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? "win-x64" : "win-x86", "lib")} {inputParameters} {input} {outputParameters} {output}";
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = path;
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();

                return Task.Run(() => true);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException($"unknown OS Platform {RuntimeInformation.OSDescription}");
            }
       }
```

И вот кусок кода на vlc:

```
public IpCamAdaptor(ControlVideoInfo info)
        {
            _videoInfo = info;
            _libVLC = new LibVLC();
            _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(_libVLC);
        }

public void StartMonitoring()
        {
            Check = true;
            _media = new Media(_libVLC, _videoInfo.PathStream.ToString(), FromType.FromLocation);
            _media.AddOption(":sout=#gather:file{dst=" + NameFile + "}");
            _media.AddOption(":sout-keep");
            _media.AddOption(":live-caching=300");
            _media.AddOption(":loop");
            _media.AddOption(":network-caching=1500");
            _media.AddOption("network-caching=1500");
            _mediaPlayer.Play(_media);
        }
```

Comment: `Task.Run(() => true)` - лайфхак `Task.FromResult(true)` :) кстати, сделать бы метод `async` и использовать `await proc.WaitForExitAsync();`, а то блокируете вызывающий поток за зря.

Comment: Что касается кодеков, есть же [библиотека готовая FFMpegCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FFMpegCore/), зачем вот это вот всё с процессами? Уж не знаю, как она будет жрать ресурсы, но точно не хуже. _что каждая запись вызывает новый процесс ffmeg.exe_ - я подозреваю, что это нормально.

Comment: Заметил еще одну странную вещь, почему вы стартуете процесс с одними и теми же аргументами дважды?

Comment: @aepot Не, у меня с vlc старт стоп в другом методе происходит, я его тут не писал. Показал пример как вызываю, через асинк можно сделать, но он мне жизнь лучше не сделает, пушо кодеки энивей бытые. Бл, вот процесс ffmpeg не хочется вызывать, у меня примерно 11 камер, а каждый процесс 20-40 мб жрет. Два раза стартую, сори, мой косяк, спешно писал. Ладно, попробую напрямую их либу юзать, потом отпишу :0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При тестировании либ поняла, что жрут ЦП они из-за кодеков, поэтому оставила vlc запись, единственное изменила формат записи на mp4. С камерами проблему решили след способом: заменили роутер и подрубили отдельно интернет для камер